# How to solve the error: query must return columns 'id', 'source', 'target' and 'cost' in postgres 9.3

Tags: qgis, postgresql, routing

```
SELECT seq, id1 AS source, id2 AS target, cost FROM pgr_kdijkstraCost(
    'SELECT gid, source, target, cost FROM road_network',
            26, array[1055,2013], false, false
```

);

I am getting the error message:

> (ERROR:  Error, query must return columns 'id', 'source', 'target' and 'cost') when run the above query in postgres....

Answer (score 1):

You have no "seq" column in the inner select, and you use the column aliases in an opposite way. I suppose you should write:

`SELECT gid as seq, source as id1, target as id2, cost FROM pgr_kdijkstraCost(...`